# JQuery .click() function or .text() not changing text

Tags: jquery

I don't know why the following code won't change the "Hi" to "Does this work" when the button is clicked. I'm pretty new to JQuery but from what I've seen nothing here is wrong. Help would be great. Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#textplace").text("Does this work?");
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <label>Text should appear here</label>
        <p id="textplace">hi</p>
    <button id="btn1">Click here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I have this JQuery with "btn1" being a button and "textplace" being a `<p>`. The paragraph is hardcoded to say "hi". But when I click the button, the text does not change. Both btn1 and textplace are the id for button and p

Comment: Please show your html

Comment: I'd check your console to see any errors. Your code looks like it should work, so I feel like it may be a selector issue.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/TXWJL/.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/95v7q/

Comment: Can you post the HTML? Are you sure those elements are using ids or are they using classes?

Comment: Using your code it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nswQR/

Comment: its updated with the html corresponding now. It wont work in both Safari and FF when I press the button.

Comment: Do you want the paragraph text to change, or the label text to change? Your code contradicts your explanation.

Comment: Copy and paste - works as expected: [jsfiddle.net/5uudy/](http://jsfiddle.net/5uudy/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#textplace").prev('label').text("Does this work?");
});
```